# python career statistic final

Tags: python, list, parsing, dictionary

I'm building a top 10 list of career statistics in python 2.6

```
html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 
html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 
html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 html_log:jeff 2153.3 1.44 125:54 2 6 41 2 7 6 3:58 599 2 6 716:36 341 36  ... continues
```

I need to beable to find the username in this case the text after the "html_log:" tags

I also need the rating (first set of values next to the username.)

Output would check the entire txt file and output the top 10 highest rated players.

Please note that there are not always 16 sets of values.

Finally the text file includes various season so player names may repeat.
If the usernames match I need the rating statistic to be added and out the the career total. 
Final output should be :

```
jeff 2268.6 * (both entries put together if usernames match)
bob 1217.1
fred 28.7
```

Comment: "why hasn't somebody done this for me yet?"

Comment: If you want help with your implementation, feel free to attempt it, and then post specific problems you have along the way. If you want people to do something for you, there are plenty of freelancers out there who would love the work, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

(Against my better judgement) I will do part of this for you:

```
txt='''\
html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 
html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 
html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 
html_log:jeff 2153.3 1.44 125:54 2 6 41 2 7 6 3:58 599 2 6 716:36 341 36
'''

stats={}
for line in txt.splitlines():
    tag=line.split(':',1)[1].split(' ',1)[0]
    stats.setdefault(tag,[]).append(line.split(':',1)[1].split(' ',1)[1])

print stats
```

Prints:

```
{'bob': ['1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 '], 
 'fred': ['28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 '], 
 'jeff': ['1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 ', '2153.3 1.44 125:54 2 6 41 2 7 6 3:58 599 2 6 716:36 341 36']}
```

The rest is up to you (split the string with the stats, deal with the ambiguous ':' in the list of stats, convert to floats, etc)